# onclick does not work properly in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, local-storage

I have a line of code that changes body background to black when particular img link is clicked, and if the img link is clicked again it returns to white. It works perfect in chrome, but in firefox it works for the first click but does not change back body background on second click. Here is the code:

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeBackground('black');return false;"><img class="img1"  src="..."></img></a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
       <script type = "text/javascript">
            function changeBackground(color) {
                if(document.body.style.background != 'black'){
                localStorage.color = document.body.style.background = color;
                }
                else if(document.body.style.background === 'black'){
                localStorage.color = document.body.style.background = 'white';
                }           
                changeBackground(localStorage.color);
            };
      </script>
```

I assume that this is not problem with onclick trigger because it works in firefox for the first click. It may be the javascript code..but I don't see anything missing...

Comment: It's probably throwing some error on FF, that is freezing your javascript execution. Have you checked the Console?

Comment: Looks like your function is endlessly recursive (it calls itself with no way to break out). http://jsfiddle.net/xn2hhh0q/1/

Comment: @showdev - you just described my job perfectly.

Comment: I find it kind-of hard to believe that this works "perfect" in Chrome. It has to at least throw an error.

Comment: I did the exactly what you did in jsfiddle in first place. But problem is that I need to store changed style so browser can use it when user goes to other pages of my site. If I do what you did above, body background color apply only on current page... Do you have any example on how to keep color while browsing through site?

Comment: Just remove the `changeBackground(localStorage.color);` from the end of the function in your question and you should be good to go.

Comment: I removed it, chrome is taking it good again, firefox - same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is infinitely recursive, meaning that it calls itself endlessly with no way to break out of the loop.

I suggest moving your `changeBackground()` call outside of your function.

I also attached the call to `window.onload` so that the `<body>` styles will be available in the DOM before the function executes.

I also loosened your `if` logic so that it's not reliant on `backgroundColor` initially being either "white" or "black".

```
function changeBackground(color) {
    if (document.body.style.backgroundColor === 'black') {
        localStorage['color'] = 'white';
    } else {
        localStorage['color'] = color;
    }
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage['color'];
}

// this sets the background color to the localStorage value when the page loads
window.onload = function () {
    changeBackground(localStorage['color']);
}
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xn2hhh0q/3/)